# Servlet Request encoding and UTF-8

Tags: jsp, servlets, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with Servlet request, 
when I try to call this url using  web service API (for example):

```
 http://localhost:8080/servlet?param=ìř
```

then HttpServletRequest have param which is decoded and contains '\u...' characters, 
instead of %. It uses some encoding, but I dont know exactly what. I tried to add to server.xml

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

but it did not help.

Do you have any ideas, how can I set charset to utf8?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might not need any `%` URL escaping, if the URI is being decoded to UTF-8 automatically by the servlet container.  Is that '\u...' actually representing a true Unicode character or is there literally a backslash, followed by a lowercase u, etc. in the URI?

Comment: well i am not sure, because among \u characters it also has Ã symbol when  tried some random parameters. The whole parameters looks like a broken decoded string

Comment: You can print the String to the console to see what is in it.